# Capture log information and raise exception in Oracle Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle11g, triggers, datatrigger

I have a requirement where the status of the column changes from x to y.
I want to capture which process changed the value from x to y in a log table
and raise an exception to roll back the update using Oracle BEFORE UPDATE trigger

Is this possible using pragma autonomous_transaction ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.  I'm assuming that you know how to identify the "process that changed the value" which I'm guessing is coming from some column in `v$session` or a user-defined context or some similar source.

You'd normally define a procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log_error( <<parameters>> )
AS
  PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
  insert into log_table ...

  commit;
END;
```

and then call that procedure from a trigger that throws an exception

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_no_x_to_y
  BEFORE UPDATE ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( :old.column = x and :new.column = y )
  THEN
    log_error;
    raise_application_error( -20001, 'Cannot change column from x to y' );
  END IF;
END;
```